# How to replace a newline at the start of a txt file with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have tried a lot, but I cannot seem to replace the new line at the start of a txt file.
So my txt file looks like this:

[image]

I just want to remove the first newline character, but everything I try does not work:
Replace ``n`r, replace \n\r or any combination of these.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(Get-Content -Path 'YourFile.txt' -Raw).TrimStart() | Set-Content -Path 'YourFile.txt' -Force
```

Or

```
(Get-Content -Path 'YourFile.txt' -Raw) -replace '^\s+' | Set-Content -Path 'YourFile.txt' -Force
```

Explanation:

The above removes all whitespace (tabs, spaces, newlines) from the top of the text, as it is impossible to see from the image if other whitespace characters are in that line or not.

If you are sure there is just the one newline, in your case `\r\n` won't work, because the file uses Unix newlines (`\n` only).

Better is to replace using `^\r?\n`. The `^` anchors at the beginning of the text. The `?` reads *zero or one* on the CR character `\r`

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that there *will* be an empty line (or you want to ignore it) you can use `Skip`.

```
Get-Content -Path 'YourFile.txt' | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path 'YourFile.txt' -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

This would replace all blank lines.  The parentheses make sure the first command finishes first if you're writing to the same file.

```
(get-content file.txt) | where { $_ } | set-content file.txt
```

Or this way, the filename goes first.

```
set-content file.txt (get-content file.txt).where{$_}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach

```
( Get-Content -Tail ( ( Get-Content testfile1 ).count-1 ) testfile1 ) | Set-Content testfile1
```

Count the number of lines in the file and then take one off the total. Use that to tail the file and write the output back to the file.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this